# How to get the array values of select boxes as an array in ajax function using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an array for my products. I took the products from drop downs. I want to save my product names using ajax. So tried to get my pname in ajax function. But I didn't get it the value of products.
This is my html part:

```
<select name="pname[]">
    <option value="">Choose product Name</option>
    <option value="1">name1</option>
    <option value="2">name2</option>
    <option value="3">name3</option>
</select>
<select name="pname[]">
    <option value="">Choose product Name</option>
    <option value="1">name1</option>
    <option value="2">name2</option>
    <option value="3">name3</option>
</select>
<select name="pname[]">
    <option value="">Choose product Name</option>
    <option value="1">name1</option>
    <option value="2">name2</option>
    <option value="3">name3</option>
</select>
```

For this I am using:

```
<script>
var name= $("#formid").find("select[name='pname']").val();
</script>
```

Also tried with

```
<script>
var name= document.getElementsByName('pname');
</script>
```

Comment: Hint: Your field's name isn't `pname`, it's `pname[]`.

Comment: And are you sure you want 3 seperate dropdowns all with the same name? It will make deciding what came from which dropdown rather difficult

Comment: Yes. I want multiple dropdowns at the same time with same name. Thats y I put the name as an array using []

Comment: Sure you dont want just `<select name="pname[]" multiple></select>` so you can collect more than one `<option>` value from a single dropdown?

Comment: Yes. I know that method, But at this time I want like this. thats y I did like this

Comment: ok well that's a slightly odd user interface, but I guess it's up to you. Anyway my first comment explains the first part of how to solve your question.

Comment: Secondly, you need to realise that .val() (as per jquery documentation) only returns the value from the first element it selects. So actually to get all the values you'd need to loop through each selected element.

Comment: Just for interest, would you show a real example of the actual HTML in these 3 dropdowns, please

Comment: Hi,can you look again in my question. i added a full html for the dropdowns

Comment: So, in this scenario is it ok for the user to select the same product 3 times? Because that could easily happen (but wouldn't be possible with RiggsFolly's solution).

Comment: Yes, the user want like this, thats Y

Comment: I dont think you have told us enough about what is really going on in this form! We are confused and therefore not able to assist you properly. Also `the user want like this` can be a dangerous reason for doing something, often they dont really know what they want, its your job to suggest a more sensible solution in these situations

Comment: Agreed, it's not your job to just blindly implement every daft idea a user comes up with. You're the technologist, so you should always challenge them if you know a better way. They might not always agree with you, but often people are happy to change their requirement if you can demonstrate an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pnames = [];
$('select').each(function() {
   pnames .push($(this).val());
})
```